# Screen periodically freezing after playing game

Tags: 20.04, games

Every time that I play Rocket League or Hoi4 the screen begins to freeze every 10 or so seconds (briefly ~1 sec). Other games don't show this behavior, at least that I've tried, and a restart fixes the issue so that leads me to believe it's not a hardware problem. Any audio playing in the background plays smoothly, and videos continue as if there was no freezing. Has anyone found a solution to this problem? I am on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LT with an RX 570 and an R5 3600.

free -h:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       5.5Gi       3.9Gi       531Mi       6.2Gi       9.2Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

systemctl vm.swappiness:

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

sudo lshw -C memory:

```
*-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: P1.00
       date: 06/04/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: e
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3000 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: CMK16GX4M2B3000C15
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3GHz (0.3ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3000 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: CMK16GX4M2B3000C15
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3GHz (0.3ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 11
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 12
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 3MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 13
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 32MiB
       capacity: 32MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
```

grep -i swap /etc/fstab:

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I have added the information

Comment: When entering lots of text output, select the pasted text, then click on the {} icon to format it into human-readable text. I already edited your question for you.

Comment: Please see my initial answer. If it helps solve your problem, please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

**swap**

Let's increase your /swapfile from 2G to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**BIOS**

ASRock b550m-itx/ac

You have BIOS 1.00.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 1.31, dated 11/6/2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/B550M-ITXac/index.asp#BIOS).

Note: Verify that I've got the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**memory**

Ryzen processors are notorious for memory compatibility issues.

Determine which Ryzen processor family you have [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/B550M-ITXac/index.asp#CPU).

Determine if your memory is supported [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/B550M-ITXac/index.asp#MemoryMS) and [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/B550M-ITXac/index.asp#MemoryRN). These are processor family specific lists.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: It's currently showing the swap total as 4.0 Gi so I believe the process worked to increase the swap total. I just rebooted and will see if the issue persists. If it does, I will reply to this thread. Thanks for the help in any event, and thanks for the heads up with the formatting

Comment: @DL Remember to tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard, so I can check your BIOS.

Comment: its an Asrock b550m-itx/ac bios v1.00, I've also tested the solution and im still getting the screen freezes.

Comment: @DL Please see the BIOS and memory updates in my answer.

Comment: I will update the bios as soon as i can. as for the memory. it is not listed under the list, this mobo was an upgrade and i guess i figured wrong that the memory was compatible. Moving forward do you see any issue with buying two of the same single dimm kit so i can run the memory in dual channel? the kits of two are significantly more expensive than buying two of the single kits

Comment: @DL Make sure you're reviewing the correct memory list. It's divided into two lists by processor family. Before changing out any memory DIMMs, run `memtest` first, and let's see if it shows any problems. You have Corsair DIMMs, correct? Those are usually fine. It's fine... you can purchase single or double kits.

Comment: I have been trying to get the memtest to run but havent been successful. It doesnt show up on the GRUB menu on boot even when it is in my system and the BIOS is set to run both uefi and legacy programs. I have also tried creating the usb image, but every time I attempt to boot from it I am met with a black screen with the white underscore blinking in the top left corner. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: @DL It might be the difference between a BIOS computer, or a UEFI computer. In your GRUB menu, do you see a `memtest` choice there? If so, go ahead and choose that one. Otherwise, try http://www.memtest.org and see if that one works for you.

Comment: @DL Status please...

Comment: dont think its the ram.I swapped the ram in another machine i had and none of the problems appeared. attempted to reboot the pc and got cpu fan spin but no signs of life on the gpu. tried swapping everything short of the cpu and all of the pieces are working. ill try to use the other psu I have to see if that might be the issue but it might be looking like a mobo problem. Note before I shut down there were missing characters and icons from the top dash (activities, current app, time, and the icons on the top right along with their menus). Never got memtest to work :/

Comment: @DL Has the problem changed? You had freezing after a game... now is the machine basically dead? Can't boot now? If you can boot, do you know how to boot with `nomodeset`? Have Nvidia? If so, what version driver? Try this to reset the Power Manager... remove AC, remove battery, hold down the power button for 30 seconds. Reconnect battery/AC and see if there's any change. Report back.

Comment: The problem has changed at this point. I was still experiencing the screen freezes after playing a game, only this last time before i shut the pc off i was also experiencing errors on the top dashboard in ubuntu where the buttons themselves were still there but little to no UI was present, just a blank bar for the most part. I shut the pc off and decided to test memory on the machine that i knew was good and had never had problems before. After replacing the memory the computer did not boot. The CPU fan spun but the gpu showed no signs of life

Comment: I have done all of those steps previously in order to make the computer boot again but none have worked. I have an RX570 that works perfectly in the other pc, and I have since tested another PSU to see if that was the problem, but i ge the same behavior. I am holding off on testing another cpumainly because of the cpu fanspin. In my experience if the cpu was dead it would turn off immediately or not even spin at all. Edit:wording

Comment: @DL re: *"decided to test memory on the machine that i knew was good and had never had problems before"*... **assuming that both machines can use the same memory**, then you've discovered some bad memory DIMMs. Did you reset the Power Manager, as per my last comment?

Comment: Yes, I have reset the power manager but there is still the same issue. And both systems are ryzen systems. I got a set of hyperx DIMMs that are listed directly on the support sheet for the mobo in question, and even with those sanctioned DIMM's, after resetting the Power Manager, the board still just gave cpu fanspin with no output. Could it be that that the corsair dimms (which work perfectly on the other pc) and the hyperx dims (which are also working on the other pc with no freezing issues) are bad?

Comment: @DL Carefully remove the quarter-sized battery from the motherboard for about 30 minutes. Re-insert and retry. Note that the BIOS should be reset to factory, so some settings may require adjustment. Without running `memtest`, we can't know anything about the DIMMs.

Comment: @DL Status please...

Comment: @DL Status please...